# Combination of two CNN models outputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have an image data set that I want to classify into 3 classes: non-disease, disease-type 1, and disease-type2.

I trained two separate CNN's models, one is classifying the 3 classes, and the second classifies only two classes: disease or non-disease.

Since the accuracy of the second model is way higher, I want to combine the output of both models, meaning, to classify as a disease type only if the first model output was type (1/2) and the second output was disease. hopefully, this will reduce the false positive error of the first model.

Is there any common way of doing that? is it O.K to do the combination only on the test set (because the training is separate) or maybe I need to separate a validation set for that?

Comment: Have you considered using a hierarchical classification approach to combine the two models (i.e. further classify the "disease" labeled observations of the disease/no-disease model by a model trained to distinguish the two diseases?

Comment: Your first model could classify two classes instead (disease-type 1 and 2). Then you could train/validate/evaluate both classifiers independently. Later combine them (as @agrei stated) into a hierarchical model